# How to make BibTeX concatenate sub-strings in the same entry

Tags: bibtex

For the BibTeX entry as below

```
booktitle = {Decision and Control, 1999. Proceedings of the 38th IEEE Conference on},
```

How to make BibTeX automatically concatenate the sub-string of "Decision and Control, 1999."
and "Proceedings of the 38th IEEE Conference on", 
so one can get "Proceedings of the 38th IEEE Conference on Decision and Control, 1999." in the
reference?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Is that really the book title? If so, that's what you should put in your bibliography. If not, then your BibTeX database entry is wrong!

Comment: Garbage In, Garbage Out!

Comment: @JosephWright That is, unfortunately, the way IEEE formats bibtex references to their own papers. I'm guessing it's a result of being able to easier index the conference alphabetically. I usually change them manually whenever I copy one of their entries into my bib files.